# How to Insert Hyperlinks into OO Writer Documents Using OpenOffice CLI Libraries

Tags: c#, itext

On the page https://api.libreoffice.org/examples/examples.html#OLE_examples
there are 2 examples of working with the OpenOffice CLI libraries.
These examples show you how to insert a hyperlink into an OO Calc document. But it is not clear how to insert a hyperlink into an OO Writer document.
Here is the code I wrote:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            unoidl.com.sun.star.uno.XComponentContext localContext =
                uno.util.Bootstrap.bootstrap();
            unoidl.com.sun.star.lang.XMultiServiceFactory multiServiceFactory =                                                      (unoidl.com.sun.star.lang.XMultiServiceFactory)localContext.
                getServiceManager();
            XComponentLoader componentLoader = (XComponentLoader)
                multiServiceFactory.createInstance("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop");
            string fileName = "c:\\Users\\sbe.CSOFT-SPB\\Documents\\OO\\1.odt";
            //string fileName = "c:\\Users\\sbe.CSOFT-SPB\\Documents\\OO\\t1.ods";
            fileName = @"file:///" + fileName.Replace('\\', '/');
            XComponent xComponent = componentLoader.loadComponentFromURL(
                fileName, "_blank", 
                0, new unoidl.com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue[0]);
            if (fileName.ToLower().EndsWith(".odt")) // OO Writer document
            {
                unoidl.com.sun.star.text.XTextDocument xTextDocument =
                    (unoidl.com.sun.star.text.XTextDocument)xComponent;
                unoidl.com.sun.star.text.XText xText = xTextDocument.getText();
                unoidl.com.sun.star.text.XSimpleText xSimpleText =
                    (unoidl.com.sun.star.text.XSimpleText)xText;
                unoidl.com.sun.star.text.XTextCursor xCursor = xSimpleText.createTextCursor();

                unoidl.com.sun.star.lang.XMultiServiceFactory xServiceMan =
                    (unoidl.com.sun.star.lang.XMultiServiceFactory)xTextDocument;

                // create a TextFrame (
                Object objTextFrame = xServiceMan.createInstance("com.sun.star.text.TextFrame");
                unoidl.com.sun.star.text.XTextFrame xTextFrame =
                    (unoidl.com.sun.star.text.XTextFrame)objTextFrame;
                unoidl.com.sun.star.awt.Size aSize = new unoidl.com.sun.star.awt.Size(15000, 400);
                ((unoidl.com.sun.star.drawing.XShape)xTextFrame).setSize(aSize);

        // insert the frame  
                xText.insertTextContent(xCursor, xTextFrame, false);  // it's OK 

                // create a hyperlink
                Object aHyperlinkObj = xServiceMan.createInstance("com.sun.star.text.TextField.URL");
                xServiceMan.createInstance("com.sun.star.text.TextField.URL");
                unoidl.com.sun.star.beans.XPropertySet xPropSet =
                    (unoidl.com.sun.star.beans.XPropertySet)aHyperlinkObj;
                xPropSet.setPropertyValue(
                    "URL", new uno.Any("http://www.example.org"));
                xPropSet.setPropertyValue(
                    "Representation", new uno.Any("hyperlink"));
 
                // ... and insert
                unoidl.com.sun.star.text.XTextContent xContent =
                    (unoidl.com.sun.star.text.XTextContent)aHyperlinkObj;
                xText.insertTextContent(xCursor, xContent, false);  // exception on this statemen
            }
            else  // OO Calc document
            {
                unoidl.com.sun.star.sheet.XSpreadsheetDocument mxDocument =
                    (unoidl.com.sun.star.sheet.XSpreadsheetDocument)xComponent;
                unoidl.com.sun.star.sheet.XSpreadsheets xSheets =  mxDocument.getSheets();
                unoidl.com.sun.star.container.XIndexAccess xSheetsIA =
                    (unoidl.com.sun.star.container.XIndexAccess)xSheets;
                unoidl.com.sun.star.sheet.XSpreadsheet xSheet =
                    (unoidl.com.sun.star.sheet.XSpreadsheet)
                    xSheetsIA.getByIndex(0).Value;

                // create a hyperlink
                unoidl.com.sun.star.lang.XMultiServiceFactory xServiceMan =
                    (unoidl.com.sun.star.lang.XMultiServiceFactory)mxDocument;
                Object aHyperlinkObj =
                    xServiceMan.createInstance("com.sun.star.text.TextField.URL");
                unoidl.com.sun.star.beans.XPropertySet xPropSet = 
                    (unoidl.com.sun.star.beans.XPropertySet)aHyperlinkObj;
                xPropSet.setPropertyValue(
                    "URL", new uno.Any("http://www.example.org"));
                xPropSet.setPropertyValue(
                    "Representation", new uno.Any("hyperlink")); 

                // ... and insert
                unoidl.com.sun.star.text.XTextContent xContent =
                    (unoidl.com.sun.star.text.XTextContent)aHyperlinkObj;
                unoidl.com.sun.star.table.XCell хCell = xSheet.getCellByPosition(0, 0);
                unoidl.com.sun.star.text.XText xText =
                    (unoidl.com.sun.star.text.XText)xCell;
                unoidl.com.sun.star.text.XTextCursor xTextCursor =
                    xText.createTextCursor();
                xText.insertTextContent(xTextCursor, xContent, false); // it's OK                     
            }
            xComponent.dispose();
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            string message = String.Format("Error.\n{0}\n{1}",
                e.Message, e.StackTrace.TrimStart());
            Debug.WriteLine(message);
        }
    }
```

Inserting a hyperlink into an OO Calc document in this code works, but on the insert statement of a hyperlink into an OO Writer document throws an exception.

Comment: [No attempt](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/). [No code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/).

Comment: Is the tag [tag:itext] really appropriate here?

Answer (score 1):

In Writer, hyperlinks are not fields, but simply a property of characters.
Basic code:

```
xCursor.setString("hyperlink")
xCursor.goLeft(9, False)
xCursor.goRight(9, True)
xCursor.HyperLinkURL = "http://www.example.org"
```

C# CLI code:

```
xCursor.setString("hyperlink");
xCursor.goLeft(9, false);
xCursor.goRight(9, true);
unoidl.com.sun.star.beans.XPropertySet xPropSet =
                        (unoidl.com.sun.star.beans.XPropertySet)xCursor;
xPropSet.setPropertyValue("HyperLinkURL", new uno.Any("http://www.example.org"));
```

Comment: Hi, I can not see your this answer had been deleted. But you posted the same question twice.